# Chartjs with JSP

Tags: jsp, chart.js

I wonder how you get to run the JavaScript framework chartjs in jsp. In the `options` section of the bar chart there is this line:

```
//Interpolated JS string - can access value
scaleLabel : "<%=value%>",
```

but `<%=` and `%>` are JSP tags. So how do you get to run it properly? Also, are there any other issues?

Comment: You can just write,   scaleLabel : "true", or scaleLabel : "false", directly.  This code is just writing a value from a JSP variable into the HTML/Javascript being created and sent to the client.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tried a simple chart but it does not behave the way I expected it to do. I will post a new question and add the link as comment here when finished.

Comment: here is my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053568/chartjs-doesnt-show-chart-properly-with-jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to specify the default if you want the default, so **try deleting the line in question**.

If you wish to keep it exactly, it must be escaped because the correct JavaScript here has a JSP Expression in it.

You can escape it with a JSP Expression.

```
scaleLabel : "<<%= "%=value%" %>>",
```

You can escape it with a JSP EL Expression.

```
scaleLabel : ${ '"<%=value%>"' },
```

Another option is to use equivalent JavaScript that does not contain a JSP Expression.

```
scaleLabel : "<" + "%=value%" + ">",
```

Comment: i tried this and it worked :                                                         `tooltipTemplate: "<"+"%if (labels){%"+"><"+"%=labels %"+">: <"+"%}%"+"><"+"%= value + ' %' %>",`