# Chartjs doesn't show chart properly with JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, chart.js

I wanted to include the JavaScript framework Chartjs into my JSP project. I tried a very simple bar chart with just one date (an average number of points). But it doesn't seem to have worked correctly. Here is a screenshot of the canvas object where I created the chart: http://i43.tinypic.com/15wc6md.png

My code is:

```
<canvas id="chartjs"></canvas>
    <script>
        //Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
        var ctx = $("#chartjs").get(0).getContext("2d");
        //This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
        var data = {
                labels : ["Durchschnittsgesamtpunktzahl aller Teilnehmer"],
                datasets : [
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        data : [<%=examAveragePoints%>]
                    }
                ]
            }

var options = {

                //Boolean - If we show the scale above the chart data           
                scaleOverlay : false,

                //Boolean - If we want to override with a hard coded scale
                scaleOverride : false,

                //** Required if scaleOverride is true **
                //Number - The number of steps in a hard coded scale
                scaleSteps : null,
                //Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
                scaleStepWidth : null,
                //Number - The scale starting value
                scaleStartValue : null,

                //String - Colour of the scale line 
                scaleLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",

                //Number - Pixel width of the scale line    
                scaleLineWidth : 1,

                //Boolean - Whether to show labels on the scale 
                scaleShowLabels : true,

                //Interpolated JS string - can access value
                scaleLabel : true,

                //String - Scale label font declaration for the scale label
                scaleFontFamily : "'Arial'",

                //Number - Scale label font size in pixels  
                scaleFontSize : 12,

                //String - Scale label font weight style    
                scaleFontStyle : "normal",

                //String - Scale label font colour  
                scaleFontColor : "#666",    

                ///Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
                scaleShowGridLines : true,

                //String - Colour of the grid lines
                scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",

                //Number - Width of the grid lines
                scaleGridLineWidth : 1, 

                //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar    
                barShowStroke : true,

                //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke    
                barStrokeWidth : 2,

                //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
                barValueSpacing : 5,

                //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
                barDatasetSpacing : 1,

                //Boolean - Whether to animate the chart
                animation : true,

                //Number - Number of animation steps
                animationSteps : 60,

                //String - Animation easing effect
                animationEasing : "easeOutQuart",

                //Function - Fires when the animation is complete
                onAnimationComplete : null

            }
        new Chart(ctx).Bar(data,options);
    </script>
```

Comment: The problem would have to be the data. You'll need to post the code that sets, or view your source in the browser and post the result of what comes out of data : [<%=examAveragePoints%>]

Comment: `examAveragePoints` is 61.666668 (it's a rounded float)

Comment: I also tried to use `61` instead of `<%=examAveragePoints%>` but this changed nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only have one object in your dataset.
Chart.js sets the object with the lowest number to 0 on the y-axis. I'm facing the same problem but I havent found a solution yet. It seems to be a common problem with Chart.js 
https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/252

Try to use a hardcoded scale.